# batch script for renaming a daily backup file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

Everyday I have a program that creates a backup file.
There is no way to set the program to keep multiple backups, it simply overwrites or removes the previous backup but I don't like that behavior.

So I was thinking about creating a batch file that would be launched through a scheduled task, but my knowledge is limited to a few commands.

For instance, let's say the backup location folder is "C:/backup" and the backup file always contain the word "skiman"

Then I would like the scrip to rename any file that contains the word "skiman" to AutoBackup01.zip and have up to 10 backups, while keeping AutoBackup01.zip as the most recent and AutoBackup10.zip as the oldest backup, and deleted any older backup older than AutoBackup10.zip. In other word, everytimes there's a new backup file it'll add +1 to every files.

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated...
I guess powershell script would do the trick too but I don't know anything about powershell.

Thanks
(PS: I'm sorry if there are some English mistakes, English isn't my mother tongue).

Comment: "a program that creates a backup file" … what program? Most backup solutions are perfectly capable of keeping incremental backups & 321 strategies.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto to what Tetsujin states here, but even if not, you can use a PowerShell FileSystemWatcher to monitor the directory where these backups are dropped, and auto rename them with the current date and time stamp as part of the file name.

Using FileSystemWatcher is a really common thing with plenty of fully documented articles and sample code on the topic.

For example:

> [Powershell FileSystemWatcher](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b)
>
> This script uses the .net FileSystemWatcher class to subscribe to
>   'create', 'change' and 'delete' events on files or folders in the NTFS
>   filesystem.It can be used to monitor a folder or folders, and can be
>   modified to perform any action upon the triggering of these events.
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b/file/42206/1/FileSystemWatcher.ps1

You tweak this to do whatever else you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple batch script. There are basically two steps:

- Renaming the file
- Delete file older than X days

Renaming the file is easy, so the first row would look like:

```
for %%f in (*skiman*) do rename "%%f" "AutoBackup%date:~10,4%%date:~6,2%/%date:~4,2%.bak"
```

Then the delete part:

```
ForFiles /p "C:\Backup" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

This will delete files older than 30 days.

So the whole file would look like:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*skiman*) do rename "%%f" "AutoBackup%date:~10,4%%date:~6,2%/%date:~4,2%.bak"
ForFiles /p "C:\Backup" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

That's it. Just name it `Rename.bat` or something like this (be aware of the `.bat` file extension), place it in the `C:\Backup` folder and run it with a scheduled task.

#### Disclaimer

The information is provided as is and was not checked if it works properly. Use it with care.

Answer (score 0):

> So, its hard to explain this to you, my English is limited....
>
> ---

Try use a bat file, where this will check:

**1)** Folder  **`c:\backup`** ->  **`exist`**

**2)** File  **`*skiman*.zip`** ->  **`exist`**

**3)** File  **`AutoBackupXY.zip`** ->  **`exist`**

**Obs:** - Considering accepting working in another numerical range:

- ***From*** **`00`** ***to*** **`09`** for keeping **`AutoBackup00.zip`** as the most recent

  - ***And***, **`AutoBackup09.zip`** as the oldest backup

    ---

```bat
@echo off && verify ^.not 2>nul || ;color 0a && ;setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_= /y /v /b " && mode 105,15 && set "_msg=*Press any key to continue^!!..."

if exist c:\Backup\nul (;cd /d "c:\Backup\." && ;title <nul && ;title ...\%~nx0)
for /f tokens^=* %%k in ('%__APPDIR__%where .:*skiman*.zip')do set "_backs=%%~k"
if not "!_backs!"=="" (set "_target=!cd!\AutoBackup#.zip") else (echo/Path: !cd!
echo=Drive/Folder/file skiman.zip not found "c:\Backup" [Error^^!!] & goto :^[ )

echo/:Copy file backup:&echo/"!_backs!"^[ok^^!!]^|^Pending renaming ^[00^-^0^9^]
for /l %%i in (9 -1 1) do for /f %%I in ('set /a %%i-1')do >nul cd. & rem./ && (
if exist "!_target:#=0%%~I!" >nul copy !_!"!_target:#=0%%~I!" "!_target:#=0%%i!"
if exist "!_target:#=0%%I!" echo/"!_target:#=0%%I!" "!_target:#=0%%i!" [ok^^!!])

if exist "!_backs!" (copy !_! "!_backs!" "!_target:#=00!">nul) else (>nul cd. &(
echo/Backup file source: "!_backs!" not found: [Error^^!!] & echo/ & goto :^[ ))
:^[ 
echo/ & echo/%_msg% && timeout -1 >nul & <nul endlocal && exit /b 1 || goto :EOF
```

---

- ***Output*** **`1st run`**:

  ---

```bat
:Copy file backup:
"C:\Backup\2020-01-09_skiman.zip"[ok!]|Pending renaming [00-09]
```

---

- ***Output*** **`2nd run`**:

```bat
:Copy file backup:
"C:\Backup\2020-01-09_skiman.zip"[ok!]|Pending renaming [00-09]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup00.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" [ok!]
```

---

- ***Output*** **`3rd run`**:

```bat
:Copy file backup:
"C:\Backup\2020-01-09_skiman.zip"[ok!]|Pending renaming [00-09]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup00.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" [ok!]
```

---

- ***Output*** **`4th run`**:

```bat
:Copy file backup:
"C:\Backup\2020-01-09_skiman.zip"[ok!]|Pending renaming [00-09]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup00.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" [ok!]
```

---

- ***Output*** **`5th run`**:

```bat
:Copy file backup:
"C:\Backup\2020-01-09_skiman.zip"[ok!]|Pending renaming [00-09]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup00.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" [ok!]
```

---

- ***Output*** **`6th run`**:

```bat
:Copy file backup:
"C:\Backup\2020-01-09_skiman.zip"[ok!]|Pending renaming [00-09]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup05.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup00.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" [ok!]
```

---

- ***Output*** **`7th run`**:

```bat
:Copy file backup:
"C:\Backup\2020-01-09_skiman.zip"[ok!]|Pending renaming [00-09]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup05.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup06.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup05.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup00.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" [ok!]
```

---

- ***Output*** **`8th run`**:

```bat
:Copy file backup:
"C:\Backup\2020-01-09_skiman.zip"[ok!]|Pending renaming [00-09]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup06.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup07.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup05.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup06.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup05.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup00.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" [ok!]
```

---

- ***Output*** **`9th run`**:

```bat
:Copy file backup:
"C:\Backup\2020-01-09_skiman.zip"[ok!]|Pending renaming [00-09]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup07.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup08.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup06.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup07.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup05.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup06.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup05.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup00.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" [ok!]
```

---

- ***Output*** **`10th run`**:

```bat
:Copy file backup:
"C:\Backup\2020-01-09_skiman.zip"[ok!]|Pending renaming [00-09]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup08.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup09.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup07.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup08.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup06.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup07.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup05.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup06.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup05.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup00.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" [ok!]
```

---

- ***Output*** **`Nth run`**: *==* `same`: ***Output***  **`10th run:`**

```bat
:Copy file backup:
"C:\Backup\2020-01-09_skiman.zip"[ok!]|Pending renaming [00-09]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup08.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup09.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup07.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup08.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup06.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup07.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup05.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup06.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup05.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup04.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup03.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup02.zip" [ok!]
"C:\Backup\AutoBackup00.zip" "C:\Backup\AutoBackup01.zip" [ok!]
```

---